# Traceroute and BGP peering

Tags: route, isp, bgp

Doing a traceroute for example:

```
1:  1ms 1ms 1ms 1.1.1.1
2:  2ms 2ms 2ms 2.2.2.2
3:  5ms 5ms 5ms 3.3.3.3
4:  9ms 9ms 9ms 4.4.4.4
```

My question is:

If the AS number of 2.2.2.2 and 3.3.3.3 are not peering directly, is it possible to get a traceroute like this(next hop not within peering partners)? is it common?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's possible if there was tunneling involved and the two end points are in different networks. You won't see the hops between the two tunnel endpoints then, just the end points itself. It's not that uncommon.